# Logout Link not working

Tags: codeigniter

So I am trying to click a logout link and end the session, and it doesnt seem to be working.

Link is located here:
application -> views-> modules -> header.php
like looks like this:

```
<a href="../admin/logout">Logout</a>
```

in the admin controller I have the function:

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    session_destroy();
    redirect('admin', 'refresh');
}
```

My routes files for admin look like this:

```
$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/view/$1';
$route['admin'] = 'admin';
```

Admin views folder is located: views -> admin

Question: When I click on my logout link it does nothing. Like in my admin if there is no session it gets redirected to a login screen. That works but when I log out if it was redirecting to the admin page which is suppose to redirect to the login page if there is no session why is nothing happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$route['admin/(:any)'] = 'admin/view/$1';`

This code is redirecting `admin/logout` to `admin/view/logout`

So, like you said, adding `$route['admin/logout'] = 'admin/logout';` near the top of your routes should take you to the correct page

Answer (score 1):

Why are you redirecting to admin on logout? Just out of curiosity.

Try this, it sounds like your link itself is the issue. Using the base_url() means you don't have to worry about relative urls getting messed up depending on the depth you are in the site.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/logout">Logout</a>
```

Comment: I could change it to redirecting to the login page, which makes more sense. But I dont think that is the issue. I feel like it is trying to go to a view page logout instead of the function logout in the controller. because now that the link looks like it is going to the right place it is giving me a 404 error: "The page you requested was not found."

Comment: Adding this to the routes file made it work    $route['admin/logout'] = 'admin/logout';